# how to show curdoc() dashboard in jupyter_notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, dashboard

I am working in jupter_notebook, and have created two dashboards. I used curdoc() to put them in one doc with two tabs as shown below, then try to output in jupyter_notebook as application, but got error.  How to fix it? Many thanks.

```
def group1_tab(df):
 ***********
 controls=WidgetBox(******)
 layout=row(controls,p)
 tab=Panel(child=layout,title='group1')
 return tab

def group2_tab(df):
  ***********
   layout=row(controls,p)
   tab=Panel(child=layout,title='group2')
   return tab

tab1 = group1_tab(df)
tab2 = group2_tab(df)

# Put all the tabs into one application
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab1, tab2])

# Put the tabs in the current document for display
curdoc().add_root(tabs)

handler=FunctionHandler(curdoc())
app=Application(handler)

show(app)

----> 1 handler=FunctionHandler(curdoc())
```

update----
finally got one works for me.

```
def make_doc(doc):
    tab1=***
    tab2=***
    tabs=Tabs(tabs=[tab1,tab2])
    doc.add_root(tabs)
show(make_doc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
handler=FunctionHandler(curdoc)
```

Instead of:

```
handler=FunctionHandler(curdoc())
```

Comment: I have tried  handler=FunctionHandler(curdoc).  The error is: ValueError: Callback functions must have signature func(doc), got func()

Comment: Well, this is probably due to the fact that you should not pass the `doc` to `FunctionHandler` but a function which receives `doc` as parameters . Something like `def create_doc(doc)` and then `handler=FunctionHandler(create_doc)` like [in this example here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/application/handlers/function.html)

Comment: I keep trying, then finally got one works for me. Response added in the question.